# How to transpose rows to column in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The script(listed below) is giving result (see screenshot 01)[Screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjlO5.png)
But the result need to be display as (See screenshot02)[Screenshot02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Kks.png).

The date in work_date (see screenshot 01) needs to be displayed as individual date column and hours in the work_hour (see screenshot 01) need to be display under individual date column.

```
DECLARE @01_STARTDATE VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @02_ENDDATE VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @STAFF INT;

SET @01_STARTDATE = '2017-07-06';
SET @02_ENDDATE = '2017-07-10';
SET @STAFF = 8;

SELECT   
    @01_STARTDATE + ' - ' + @02_ENDDATE AS [Date Range],
    SU.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + SU.LAST_NAME AS Staff,
    f.FACILITY_NAME AS Site_Name,
    P.PRJ_PROJECT_NAME AS Project_Name,
    R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME AS Project_Type_Brownfield,
    '' AS Project_Type_VRP,
    st.work_hour, st.work_date
FROM 
    FAC_FACILITY AS f
INNER JOIN 
    GOV.PRJ_PROJECT AS P ON f.FACILITY_RID = p.FACILITY_RID
INNER JOIN 
    GOV.SYS_TIME_LOG AS ST ON ST.PRJ_PROJECT_RID = P.PRJ_PROJECT_RID
LEFT JOIN 
    SEC_USER AS SU ON SU.USER_RID = ST.USER_RID
LEFT JOIN 
    GOV.REF_PROJECT_TYPE AS R ON P.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID
WHERE 
    ST.WORK_DATE BETWEEN CAST(@01_STARTDATE AS DATE) AND CAST(@02_ENDDATE AS DATE)
    AND ST.USER_RID = @STAFF        
    AND R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = 3
GROUP BY 
    f.FACILITY_NAME, P.PRJ_PROJECT_NAME, SU.FIRST_NAME,
    st.work_date, SU.LAST_NAME, R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME,
    st.work_hour

UNION ALL

SELECT   
    @01_STARTDATE + ' - ' + @02_ENDDATE AS [Date Range],
    SU.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + SU.LAST_NAME AS Staff,
    f.FACILITY_NAME AS Site_Name,
    P.PRJ_PROJECT_NAME AS Project_Name,
    '' AS Project_Type_Brownfield,
    R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME AS Project_Type_VRP,
    st.work_hour, st.work_date
FROM
    FAC_FACILITY AS f
INNER JOIN 
    GOV.PRJ_PROJECT AS P ON f.FACILITY_RID = p.FACILITY_RID
INNER JOIN 
    GOV.SYS_TIME_LOG AS ST ON ST.PRJ_PROJECT_RID = P.PRJ_PROJECT_RID
LEFT JOIN 
    SEC_USER AS SU ON SU.USER_RID = ST.USER_RID
LEFT JOIN 
    GOV.REF_PROJECT_TYPE AS R ON P.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID
WHERE 
    ST.WORK_DATE BETWEEN CAST(@01_STARTDATE AS DATE) AND CAST(@02_ENDDATE AS DATE)
    AND ST.USER_RID = @STAFF        
    AND R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = 2
GROUP BY 
    f.FACILITY_NAME, P.PRJ_PROJECT_NAME, SU.FIRST_NAME,
    st.work_date, SU.LAST_NAME, R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME,
    st.work_hour

UNION ALL

SELECT   
    @01_STARTDATE + ' - ' + @02_ENDDATE AS [Date Range],
    SU.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + SU.LAST_NAME AS Staff,
    g.grant_name AS Site_Name,
    '' AS project_name,
    '' AS Project_Type_Brownfield,
    '' AS Project_Type_VRP,
    st.work_hour, st.work_date
FROM
    (SELECT 
         SUM(work_hour) AS work_hour, user_rid,
         grant_rid, work_date
     FROM  
         GOV.SYS_TIME_LOG
     WHERE 
         WORK_DATE BETWEEN CAST(@01_STARTDATE AS DATE) AND CAST(@02_ENDDATE AS DATE)
         AND USER_RID = @STAFF        
         AND grant_rid = 1
     GROUP BY 
         grant_rid, user_rid, work_date) AS ST
LEFT JOIN 
    SEC_USER AS SU ON SU.USER_RID = ST.USER_RID
LEFT JOIN 
    SYS_GRANT AS G ON st.grant_rid = g.grant_rid
WHERE 
    ST.WORK_DATE BETWEEN CAST(@01_STARTDATE AS DATE) AND CAST(@02_ENDDATE AS DATE)
    AND ST.USER_RID = @STAFF        
    AND st.grant_rid = 1
GROUP BY 
    SU.FIRST_NAME, st.work_date, SU.LAST_NAME,
    G.Grant_name, st.work_hour;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Pivot Table with multiple column with dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300884/sql-server-pivot-table-with-multiple-column-with-dates)

Comment: If you are using a RDBMS supporting PIVOT then look into your vendors documentation on that command. Since you tagged TSQL then I would suggest looking into third party reporting tools. This kind of rollup does not lend itself well to standard SQL and can get clumsy and error prone.

Comment: Why are your date variables varchar? What is the datatype in the column? A dynamic PIVOT or dynamic cross tab is likely what you need here. Not really sure why you are using UNION ALL here. You could do that with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous examples available of how to "**pivot**" output such as your first image to look like the second. Additionally because you change the date range by parameters you will need to adopt "**dynamic sql**" to produce the "**dynamic column names**".

Please note that you do not need to run 3 separate queries to gather the information you want, but you should wait to the very last moment in your query to suppress output of values. Ideally you would not do this at all using SQL, but would perform this in the "presentation layer" (this query looks like it is designed for a report and most reporting products support conditional output of data).

It will simply your query a lot and make a pivot more achievable, if you include `PROJECT_TYPE_RID` into both the select and group by clause you can control output using case expressions like this:

```
    case when R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = 1 then '' else Project_Name end  AS Project_Name,
    case when R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = 3 then R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME else '' end AS Project_Type_Brownfield,
    case when R.PROJECT_TYPE_RID = 2 then R.PROJECT_TYPE_NAME else '' end AS Project_Type_VRP,
```

**BUT note**, because you want to use PIVOT, you will NOT be able to do this suppress values like this until AFTER the pivot has been performed.